# Does the thisDocument.Content include the page break which I insert to the end of the document by programming?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-interop

I am developing the document level program of Office2007 using C#, and I have the following issue: 
Inside the building block gallery, there are many custom tables which I already stored previously. Now, I would like to insert some of them to the opening document, after inserting one specific building block(table inside) into the end of the document, I insert a page break after the table so that next table starts from a new page, below is my code:

```
Word.Range rg = theDoc.Content;
rg.Collapse(ref  collapseEnd);//collapse = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
Word.Range insertedRange = utl.InsertIntoRange(rg, buildBlockName);//The InsertIntoRange method just retrieve the specific buildingblock and insert it into the range using the buildBlock's Insert method
insertedRange.Collapse(ref collapseEnd);
insertedRange.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
```

the code above lays in a button callback, when I first click the button, it worked as expected(Insert the table, and the a page break). However, when I click the button and the code above executed again, it just deletes the pagebreak which I inserted last time.
I have no idea why, I search many material online, but none of them could solve my problem, I guess the theDoc.Content just does not include the last page break? if so? How could I insert something inside the buildingblock into the document, and then add a page break after table?
Any help will be appreciated!

After doing some research, I narrow down the issues to building block insertion operation.
Below is my utl.InsertIntoRange(rg, buildBlockName) method

```
object categories = "test";
object isRichText = (object)true;
Word.Template tp = doc.Application.Templates[1];
Word.Categories ctgs = tp.BuildingBlockTypes.Item(Word.WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeCustom1). Categories;
object buildBlockNameObj = (object) buildBlockName;

try{
    Word.Category ctg1 =ctgs.Item(ref categories);
    return ctg1.BuildingBlocks.Item(ref buildingBlockNameObj).insert(rg, ref isRichText);

}
```

If I insert a section normal text, the previous page break will not be deleted, however, If I insert a building block with the code above, the table will be inserted into the end of the document and delete the last page break I just inserted! 
This problem is just gonna drive me crazy

Comment: The basic structure of your code works fine for me. Of course, I can't test with the same content... You might try testing with a Building Block that's just plain text, just to see you get a different result. Something you can try, instead of a manual page break, is to format the first paragraph of the table with "Page Break Before". Something like: Word.Paragraph para = insertedRange.Paragraphs[1]; para.PageBreakBefore = -1;

Answer (score 0):

> > Does the thisDocument.Content include the page break which I insert to the end of the document by programming?

Yes. You can verify it get the characters of the content. Then insert the page break using the code. At last if you get the characters again, you will find that two characters more than before.

Here is a piece of VBA to insert the “Hello” and a page break every time you run. Could this work for you?

```
Sub InsertText()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

rng.InsertAfter "Hello!"
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
rng.InsertBreak wdPageBreak

End Sub
```

And what’s the code for the utl.InsertIntoRange method?

Comment: I also try to insert the build block however still worked. It seems the issue is relative to the content of the specific build block. You may upload a demo template to help us test.